# Does Keycloak support basic Authentication?

Tags: java, keycloak

Does Keycloak support basic Authentication (Authorization header that contains the word Basic word followed by a space and a base64-encoded string username:password ) and if so how I can configure realm and client settings for it ?
I want to secure my rest api with Keycloak and support also basic Authentication as an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes that's possible for clients with `Access Type: confidential` and `Direct Access Grants Enabled`. You can find more details on these settings in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients).

You also need to enable `enable-basic-auth` and supply your `credentials`in your application settings. Consult the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config) for more details.

Comment: Hi @kulatamicuda Could you please tell me how you setup this? I am also stuck on this. I have configured keycloak but want to have basic auth also access api so Please let me know how you specified the username and pasword in keycloak?

Comment: @DashrathMundkar Exactly as written by Joe. You will need to specify Access Type: confidential and Direct Access Grants Enabled for such client in Keycloak and in our Spring Application properties we have keycloak.enable-basic-auth=true

Comment: @DashrathMundkar we have not specified username and password, our setup is federation  with MS AD so for authorisation is used the same user name as is  in MS AD and user password from MS AD. The access is than controlled by application roles which are mapped onto MS AD groups. So authentication is basic and authorisation is checked against MS AD. If you do not want integration with MS AD, you can specify username and password directly in Keycloak realms.

Comment: Is this still true?
Since 8.0.0 the credenial support was removed https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/#credentials-support-removed-from-the-javascript-adapter

Comment: The example link is sadly broken!

Comment: @Peter yes, but I can confirm it still works at least with Keycloak 12.0.4 with the parameters and setup written as an answer