# Enable basic auth with Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, basic-authentication, keycloak-rest-api

I would like to call Keycloak Rest APIs using basic auth. To do so I've tried following what is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808046/does-keycloak-support-basic-authentication) but there are missing links.

I've set the clients access type to `confidential` and set `Direct Access Grants Enabled`.

Apparently `enable-basic-auth` needs to be specified in the `Java Adapter Configuration` but I can't see how this is done. The documentation mentions it's a JSON file which makes it sound like I add it in my Keycloak directory as a configuration.

Lastly I've seen mentions of using a generated secret. I can generate a secret in the `Credentials` tab however I can't find references in the documentation about how I use this.

What do I need to do to enable basic authentication correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two parameters `enable-basic-auth` and `credentials` in the keycloak.json file which you have to place in the WEB-INF folder.

```
{
  "realm": "<REALM_NAME>",
  "auth-server-url": "<KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "<CLIENT_ID>",
  "public-client": false,
  "credentials": "<CLIENT_CREDENTIAL_FROM_CREDENTIALS_TAB>",
  "enable-basic-auth": true
}
```